# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus

Tags: java, web-services, http, quarkus

I am trying to run runner jar of the quarkus application which would be listening over port 9411 on http.

Programmatically using UrlClassLoader, when I try to load the jar it throws
(also with java -jar)
1.java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus

2.java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
here is the snippet of code ,

```
        URLClassLoader loader = new URLClassLoader(
            new URL[]{ new File(<location of runner jar>).toURI().toURL()});
        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader);
        Class<?> mainClass = loader.loadClass("io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain"); 
        Method mainMethod = mainClass.getMethod("main", String[].class);
        mainMethod.invoke(null, (Object) new String[]{});
```

another observation is when I place /lib folder at the runner jar location it loads successfully meaning it requires the lib folder altogether.

How can I make my code work only with runner jar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To produce a fat jar that includes all the libraries necessary to run the app, use the property `quarkus.package.uber-jar=true` (you can add that into `src/main/resources/application.properties` or pass it as a system property when running the build).

Comment: Yes, this works for me. I've noticed that the `uber-jar=true` setting is also respected when the Maven plug-in builds a container image. I'm curious to know why this _isn't_ the default.

Comment: Thanks Jan, this way we get rid of other jar and only have single jar with all the dependencies

Answer (score 3):

With mvn clean package I got the following error starting:

```
 Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.package.uber-jar" was provided
```

I've found

```
 quarkus.package.type=uber-jar
```

as a property.

What I prefer is setting

```
 <quarkus.package.type>uber-jar</quarkus.package.type>
```

in the pom properties.

https://github.com/fluentcodes/sandbox/tree/java-quarkus-empty

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to build an _über-jar with Gradle

```bash
./gradlew build -Dquarkus.package.type=uber-jar
```

2. If anyone is using `serverless framework`, make sure your artifact is `function.zip` not a jar in Quarkus JDK mode.

```yaml
package:
  artifact: build/function.zip
```

3. If anyone is using ALB to invoke the lambda then you have to replace the `'io.quarkus:quarkus-amazon-lambda'` by `'io.quarkus:quarkus-amazon-lambda-rest'`  in your grade. In that case, you don't need to provide a custom handler implementation.